# "Sending data to printer" status when sending task from "Kubuntu" to "Kubuntu with shared printer". Windows to Kubuntu works ok

Tags: networking, printing

I have Kubuntu 19.10 with a Canon printer connected via USB (lets call it a **server** with IP 192.168.1.120). I installed the driver + shared this printer. Printing from the server (ie local printing) works ok. Additionally I connected few Windows PCs to the shared printer using downloaded driver for Windows from Canon site and using the path `http://192.168.1.120:631/printers/Canon_MF110-910_Series` it also works ok.

Then I needed to connect one more PC with Kubuntu 19.10 in the same network to the shared printer and here I got a problem (the printer driver and ISO of Kubuntu are the same in case of the server and this remote PC):

1. I connected this remote PC to the shared printer using the same path as on Windows: `http://192.168.1.120:631/printers/Canon_MF110-910_Series`;
2. Task/document is sent successfully to the server (I see task on the server in the printing queue);
3. Printing stuck with the `Sending data to printer` status;
4. So, as a result the Server is able to receive task from the remote Kubuntu PC but does not want to print it.

How can it be fixed?